# Passing two dates to alert

Tags: javascript

In javascript, I'm running this:

```
var y2k = new Date(Date.UTC(2000,0));
var allFives = new Date(Date.UTC(2005,4,5,5,55,55));
alert(y2k, allFives);
```

I get `Sat Jan 01 2000 00:00:00 GMT+0000 (GMT)` from `alert`. I was expecting something like: `Sat Jan 01 2000 00:00:00 GMT+0000 (GMT), Thu May 05 2005 05:55:55 GMT+0000 (GMT)`.

What happens when two dates are passed as arguments to `alert`?

Comment: alert function takes just one argument

Comment: As per spec, alert takes only one argument https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/alert .. second one is ignored.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

alert() assumes this structure:

```
 alert(some expression)
```

so you can either convert them to strings and then pass in alert

```
var y2k = new Date(Date.UTC(2000,0)).toString();
var allFives = new Date(Date.UTC(2005,4,5,5,55,55)).toString();
alert(`${y2k}, ${allFives}`);
```

Answer (score 2):

alert() expects only one argument. `alert(some expression)`  you can achieve your output by concatenating variables like -

```
var y2k = new Date(Date.UTC(2000,0));
var allFives = new Date(Date.UTC(2005,4,5,5,55,55));
alert(y2k + ", " + allFives);
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/alert

Answer (score 1):

Only one variable should be passed into alert function.

```
var y2k = new Date(Date.UTC(2000,0));
var allFives = new Date(Date.UTC(2005,4,5,5,55,55));
alert(y2k + ', ' + allFives);
```